# Message Dialog "No connectivity" etc. in Glass Activity

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431359/no-connectivity-message-in-ok-glass-menu), but I want something different.

I noticed that, when you don't have any connectivity, and you try to start Speech Recognition in an app, say through the `RecognizerIntent` class, you get a "*no network connectivity - tap to view connectivity status*" (see attached image), and if you click, a new Card with connectivity status appears.

[image]

How can I copy this behaviour in my own Activity, using the GDK?

EDIT: here is my code to call the Speech Recognition:

```
Intent speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
if (speechIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Talk to set your title:");
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting to record speech title");
    startActivityForResult(speechIntent, Constants.SPEECH_TITLE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I later found an answer to my problem. I'm using the `MessageDialog` class [provided by pif](https://github.com/pif/glass-progress-bar)

Here is how I am calling the card:

```
MessageDialog localDialog = new MessageDialog.Builder(context)
    .setMessage("No network connectivity")
    .setSecondaryMessage("Tap to view connection settings")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_cloud_sad_medium)
    .setIsError(true)
    .setDismissable(true)
    .setAutoHide(false)
    .setExpanded(true)
    .setShowProgress(false)
    .setIsManual(false)
    .setListener(new MessageDialog.SimpleListener() {
            
    public boolean onConfirmed() {
        Log.d(TAG+"_noConnDialog", "onConfirm");
        return true;
    }

    public void onDismissed() {
        Log.d(TAG+"_noConnDialog", "onDismissed");
        ((Activity)context).finish();
    }

    public void onDone() {
        Log.d(TAG+"_noConnDialog", "onDone");
        Intent localIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
        localIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        localIntent.putExtra("settings_id", 0);
        context.startActivity(localIntent);
        ((Activity)context).finish();
    }
}).build();
localDialog.show();
```

Notice that, as indicated in pif's disclaimer,

> This is just for educational purposes and should not be used in any production apps until Google releases something similar officially.
>
> I hope, Google will publish a set of Google Glass Views in the future releases of GDK. We really need them! Especially that awesome progress bar!

AFAIK the Glass Developer Team has not released these functionalities in the GDK yet.